# Photo display for Android gallery

Tags: android

I can open the gallery with this code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("photo/*");

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Photo"), PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST );
```

What changes do I need to do to the code to open the gallery to display only photo?

How can I get the real path of the selected photo when the results are returned?

Answer (score 0):

First change you intent instantiation to this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

And then later in your onActivityResult() do this

```
if (requestCode == PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST && result == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri selectedImageUri = resultIntent.getData();
}
```